# send binary data (image) to printer using curl ..!

Tags: curl

i am trying to send an image file to printer using curl. I am using curl command line tool for this and the command i used is "curl --data-binary @filename ip:port". But this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: user - what does not work ? include the error message or error code ...

Comment: I am able to get  print of a text file using curl --data-binary "@textfile.txt" printerip:port. But i need to get print of an image..

Answer (score 1):

The data to be printed also needs to be passed in a format that the printer can understand, just throwing a JPEG into an IPP request may not be enough; it may need conversion to something like Postscript, PCL, or else, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most cases of file uploads from a form in HTML and over HTTP use multipart formposts. You do such posts with curl using a number of -F on the command line.

As always, start out by reading this guide on how to script with HTTP:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html